# Disk images or containers in iOS

Tags: ios, zip, containers, dmg

I've had an app on the App Store for the last 8 years.  It's getting quite large, and has a huge number of discrete files, currently around 32,000. (Almost all are RTFDs and JPEGs).  XCode, therefore, is sloooow.  A complete fresh build takes about 25 minutes to launch on a 2018 MBP with an i9 processor.  Which is not good for my blood pressure OR my productivity.  Part of this is XCode bloat in recent years, but a good chunk is my own doing.

Installation on the iOS side is also slow.  I've had the app rejected, incorrectly, by App Review.

I would like to use some kind of container approach for these files.  A note to Developer Technical Support indicates that, no, Apple does not support disk images in iOS.

Is anyone familiar with any methods of containerizing files, even something third-party, that would work with file references and the API du jour (Cocoa, Swift)?

Comment: Interesting - what's the name of your app? Can you not just store all your jpegs remotely ?

Comment: Remote storage is where we're headed, but the app can be used in remote areas, which can be problematic.